# What is good way to check a key of a dictionary in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a loop that over some values. I have a dictionary that it's keys are in the values of the loop iteration.

I can't change the outer loop.

```
for i in range(1, 1000000000000):
    if i in my_dict.keys():
        func()

other_func(i)
```

Each element in: `my_dict.keys()` appears in `range(1, 1000000000000)`.
However the number of elements in `my_dict.keys()` is much smaller than
the number of iterations.

The problem is that each if check is time consuming. What is a good way of handling this?

Comment: This sounds like a typical [XY Proble](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) question. What exactly is it that you want to achive? Do you have a list of certain numbers you want? Also a quicker way would be `if i in my_dict`?

Comment: `my_dict.keys()` creates a list *every time it is called*. And searching through that list is a linear search. Changing to `if i in my_dict` is your no-brainier first massive speed up.

Comment: Why dont you just do `for i in my_dict.keys():`?

Comment: Oh, and that massive range has got to go. @AKS has the right idea below.

Comment: Have you considered moving to Python 3? You could iterate over `my_dict` and check if the key is `in range(1, 1000000000000)` with good performance.

Comment: The for loop must iterate over range(1, 1000000000000)

Comment: Since you are using Python 2 and cannot change the outer loop (I don't understand why) change `range` to `xrange`.  `xrange` returns an iterater while `range` creates a list. Preallocating a list that large is probably eating all your ram and causing you to swap to disk.  Combine that with `if i in my_dict:` (no `.keys()`) and you will see a huge speed up.

Answer (score 9):

I think you can do something like this:

```
for i in my_dict:
   if 0 < i < 1000000000000:
       func()
```

`range(1, 1000000000000)` will generate a list of numbers from `1` to `999999999999` and you just need to check if your key is in that range. So you don't really need to generate the list using `range` itself.

Comment: if `len(my_dict)` is more than 1000000000000, it will be slower :).

Comment: Well, here what OP says: _However the number of elements in my_dict.keys() is much smaller than the number of iterations_

Comment: And, whatever is the number of keys this solution is always `O(n)` So of course if the number of elements in the dict increases, the time taken will increase linearly. So, I really don't understand why do you mention that it will be slower only if  `len(my_dict)` is more than `1000000000000`.

Comment: One more minor improvement: drop `.keys()`. There is no need to create a temporary list of keys for iteration since default iteration is by key. `for i in my_dict:`

Comment: @avicohen: It seems your indentation is off. Also, I don't think it is a good practice to change the scope of the question dynamically.

Comment: @AKS sorry, I didn't read that *However the number of elements in my_dict.keys() is much smaller than the number of iterations*

Answer (score 0):

Change your for loop. See below script.

```
for key in my_dict.keys():
    if 0 < int(key) < 1000000000000:
        func()
```

Change for loop because in original implementation for loop would iterate at most 1000000000000 times. But now it will iterate maximum of length of my_dict.

Comment: `range(1, 10000000)` would generate a list/iterator each call. This is also extremely time consuming.

Comment: Yes, updating my answer

Answer (score 0):

Well, `try` and `except` is a good way to go.

```
for i in range(1, 100000000):
    try:
        my_dict[i]
    except KeyError:
        continue
    func()
```

If `i` is not in the `keys`, then it will throw `KeyError` and will go to the next iteration. If `i` is proper `key` then the `func()` will be called.

Comment: It will still time consuming.

Comment: @ismailsunni Well right, but less consuming than original solution. Personally I like AKS solution.

Answer (score 0):

The most simplest way is ,

if my_dict.has_key('key'):